SSRS: Add column number in matrix
I am creating a matrix to show salary breakdown of employees in Matrix. Since salary components are dynamic and can vary employee to employee, I used matrix. The matrix will look similar to the following



Employee Code
Employee name
Basic
HRA
Travel Allowance
Special Allowance
Total




1
2
3
4
5
6
7


07686
Alex
5687.00
657.00
102.00

6446.00


08761
Nick
5375.00
650.00

205.00
6230.00



Please note the row with the serial number in the above table is part of table header. Basic, HRA, Travel Allowance, Special Allowance are columns of matrix (dynamic). There can be even more salary components. Rest of the fields like Employee Code, Employee Name and Total are static fields.
The problem I am facing is to show the column serial number. Need help to generate and show the serial number dynamically.
Thanks in advance.

You can add the following custom code in your report
Dim columnCount As Integer= 0

Public Function columnNumber() As Integer

columnCount = columnCount + 1
Return columnCount

End Function

Use the function in the required columns



That is a great help! Worked like a charm
